# UIBezierPath not equally fat everywhere and cut off

Tags: swift, uikit, core-graphics, uibezierpath, quadratic-curve

I am trying to draw a **line with a smooth quadratic curve attached** to its end. Therefore, I am using this code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class IndicatingView: UIView {
    var path: UIBezierPath!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    func createLineWithCurve() {
        path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))

        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height - self.frame.width))

        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height))
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.createLineWithCurve()

        path.lineWidth = 3
        // Specify a border (stroke) color.
        UIColor.purple.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**And the output I get looks quite good already:**

[image: Output]

However, as you can see, the quad-curve is fatter than the normal line. Also, the quad-curve seems to be cut off at the bottom. How can I fix that? I want the path to be completely smooth without looking fatter at some points or being cut-off somehow.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: i am pretty sure the "cut off" thing is because you are painting out of your rect... ;) don't paint your line at 0,0 but add your linewidth to it...so move to (linewidth/2, linewidth/2) instead of (0,0)....and do the same on all edges...

Comment: @Chris okay but if I look at my code I'm strictly using the view's frame so how is it even possible to paint out of my rect?

Comment: because of the linewidth ...it is 3

Comment: What if you turn off antialiasing?

Comment: thanks @matt I found the issue.... look at the accepted answer - I didn't take the line with into consideration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your path is getting clipped by the bounds of the view. For example, in your vertical stroke starting at `0, 0`, half of the path’s vertical stroke will fall outside of the left edge of the view.

You should use [`insetBy(dx:dy:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1454218-insetby) to inset the stroked path by half the line width, which will ensure the whole stroke will fall within the `bounds` of the view. And then use `minX`, `maxX`, etc. of that resulting inset `CGRect` to figure out the various `CGPoint` for your path.

For example:

```
class IndicatingView: UIView {
    func lineWithCurve() -> UIBezierPath {
        let lineWidth: CGFloat = 3
        let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: lineWidth / 2, dy: lineWidth / 2)

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.lineWidth = lineWidth
        path.lineCapStyle = .square

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))            
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY - rect.width))
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))

        return path
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        UIColor.purple.setStroke()
        lineWithCurve().stroke()
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

here you see my "result" -> i made the linewidth a bit bigger that you can see, it paints perfect ;)

Apple draws always exactly on point, so if you paint a line of width 3 on point 0,0, one point is -1,0, one on 0,0 and one on 1,0

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer... this is interesting. The problem I have is that I can't make the line thicker than 3 - the curve will be quite small on the screen so I can't make it 10